# How to execute script in compute nodes using nrpe?

Tags: scripting, hpc, nagios, nrpe

I want to execute script using nrpe in selected compute nodes and output the result

I want to run scripts on compute nodes. I can select the compute nodes and input command to execute. Executed result will be given as output. I want to provide the compute nodes where the scripts are to be executed.

Comment: This is a very low quality question. Please describe what you have done, and what isn't working as expected.

Comment: In front end we can input the script and can select on what compute nodes it can run. This data will be send to back-end that is made to run commands using ssh on the head node console.(Using this headnode only we can access the compute nodes). How should I use Nrpe to execute this script on the selected compute nodes?